# Possible to read the last line of a linux gnu-screen?

Tags: linux, bash, gnu-screen

I'm trying to make a simple and reliable script, preferably in bash, that is executed every minute using crontab. The script simply has to read the contents of the last couple of lines of an open screen and store them as a var so that I can search for a sub-string. Does anyone know of an easy way to do this, thanks.

Comment: Nothing at all, because I don't know of a way for bash to "read output" from within a screen. Essentially that's all I need since the rest of my script is written. I've considered trying to use -L to log screen to a file then read from that, but that obviously takes up more space and could lead to issues as the script is designed to find a certain error code in a program that runs in screen, then kills the screen and opens a new one. It may be impossible, I just figured I would ask the community to see if they had any suggestions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can send the `hardcopy` command to the screen and read the last line using the `tail` command:

```
screen -X hardcopy "~/test.log"
tail -n1 ~/test.log
```

Comment: I'm not sure what OS you are on to claim that `last` and `tail` are similar in any way. Other than that your answer really helped.